# Aiogram не могу отправить фото ссылкой aiogram

Tags: aiogram

````
async def sendall(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.from_user.id == config.owner:
            text = message.text[9:]
            users = db.get_users()
            keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            url_button = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Нажми, чтобы перейти по ссылке", url="https://example.com")
            keyboard.add(url_button)
            for row in users:
                try:
                    await bot.send_message(row[0], text, reply_markup=keyboard)
                    if int(row[1]) != 1:
                        db.set_active(row[0], 1)
                except:
                    db.set_active(row[0], 0)
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Успешная рассылка')```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужен изменить и дополнить этот код чтобы можно было отправлять не только ссылку с текстом но и фото

Comment: await bot.send_photo(photo_id, caption = text, reply_markup=keyboard)